# Where does NullPointerException is thrown?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

If I'm doing something like this:

```
String str = null;
str.toLowerCase();
```

Here I will have a NullPointerException and I want to know where an exception will be created. Does JVM manage such cases and throws NullPointerException or at compile time there are some checks for that case in com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type class?

I can't find a good article which will explain it to me and I also can't find anything related to Runtime exception throwing in OpenJDK javac sources. Can anyone base explanation or link to book\article where I can read about Runtime exceptions creation?

Comment: As the name implies, `RuntimeException`s like `NullPointerException` are thrown at run time.

Comment: @Dragondraikk: I'd accept that as an answer; but I can positively flag this as a comment :)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Honestly, I find that a bit too simple to submit as an answer. If it helps OP, I'm happy enough.

Comment: I know that it will be thrown at runtime, but who is in charge for this? JVM ?

Comment: @AlexandrRadchykov: who else?

Comment: @Dragondraikk: I do agree on the "too simple", but I think it's better to have a votably "good" answer than just a comment, for future generations (*"someone think of the children!!"*)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Is there are a possibility to add such checks (as null checks at runtime) for the JVM through the compilation process?

Comment: The easiest way would be through a normal `try-catch` block. I don't think there's a way to do so at compile-time without writing your own compiler from the ground up.

Comment: I've forked javac from OpenJDK and I already add compile time checking for null assigning to special kind of variables, but I've no idea how to add runtime check will exception throwing.  So I can do with compiler whatever I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this part **I want to know where an exception will be created** ? or Title itself **Where does NullPointerException is thrown?**

> It's is created on the same *call Stack*, which is the ordered list of
>   methods that had been called to get to the method where the error
>   occurred which then searches for a method that contains a block of
>   code that can handle the exception (i.e exception handler).

[image: Searching the call stack for the exception handler.]
Image Source Oracle.

Answering your this part

**or at compile time there are some checks for that case ?**

> No

because A
**checked exceptions.** must be caught somewhere in your code. If not code will not compile. That's why they're called checked exceptions.

Since

```
String str = null;
str.toLowerCase();
```

*you will be able to compile without handling any Exceptions*, so is not a checked exception 
(You can look for better formal definition on the web).

By now you know that NullPointerException is not a checked exceptions.

Quoting [JSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html)

> The unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) are exempted from compile-time checking. i.e all the runtime 
>   exceptions

These RuntimeException are thrown when these are detected by the methods because **it encountered an error in the virtual machine `runtime`**